# Need guidance on a unity augmented reality project

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, markers

Am looking to build a mobile app, where the user will choose the marker area, where he wants the dynamic objects to appear. The list of available dynamic objects will be from a web service. Once you place the marker, user will be able to choose the object and then it will appear automatically on that spot. User should be able to move that object around, to see different views of it, modify the color etc.

I am new to Unity & Vuforia. I did learn some basic apps like creating a target image and when that image appears, show something on that target etc. But for this use case of mine, am not clear on where to start. Can someone guide me on how /where to start? I want to go step by step and make this, by learning it.  Good blog posts or videos or tutorials on each of the concepts will be helpful for me, in learning and building it.

Thanks for our help.

Answer (score 2):

What you wanted is to create a user defined image target and load assetbundle from specified url ,the given below links will help you to achieve this...

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-AssetBundles-to-Package-Augmentations

For user defined image target:

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/User-Defined-Targets-Guide